# Iterate through dictionaries within a list within a dictionary in python - return values based on condition

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

I want to scrape weather forecast data, more precisely, I want to get data from a dict which has a list with multiple dicts:

```
  data = {'city': BERLIN,
 'list': [{'date': '2018-10-19 18:00:00',
       'weather': {'temp': 12.86,
                'temp_max': 13.98,
                'temp_min': 12.86},
       'wind': {'deg': 64.5011, 'speed': 1.32}},
      {'date': '2018-10-20 18:00:00',
       'weather': {'temp': 15.86,
                'temp_max': 18.48,
                'temp_min': 12.84},,
       'wind': {'deg': 144.507, 'speed': 1.92}},
    ....
```

The tricky part is that I want it to return the 'wind' key in the dictionary, where the date is equal to a SATURDAY.

At the end, I'd like to have something like: 
{Saturday, 'wind': {'deg': 144.507, 'speed': 1.92}}

I have looped through 'list', but am lost how to check for Saturday of the date:

```
    for item in data.get('list'):
print(item.get('date'))
print(item.get('wind'))
```

returns:

```
    2018-10-20 18:00:00
{'speed': 3.92, 'deg': 294.003}
    2018-10-20 21:00:00
{'speed': 3.57, 'deg': 276.001}
```

To retrieve day and wind keys I tried:

```
    for item in data.get('list'):
print(item.get(datetime.strptime('date','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').weekday()))
```

But get the error that 'time data 'date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S''

Comment: `'date'` should be the date you want to format, not the literal string `date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do **three** things.

1. Iterate through a list of dictionaries.
2. Convert `date` to a week day.
3. Check if week day is `Saturday`.

---

The first step you already got nailed, but you don't need to use `get()` method to access keys in a dictionary. Using square brackets works too.

`for item in data['list']:
    do something`

---

When you are inside the loop you need to grab the value from the `date` key and then convert it to a `datetime object` by using the `datetime.strptime()` function. Now you're doing this on a string with the value `date`.

**You are doing this:** `datetime.strptime('date','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

**It should be this:** `datetime.strptime(item['date'],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

After you have converted the value from the `date` key you could store it in a variable and use the `strftime()` method to convert it to a week day string by calling it with `%A`.

---

The third and last step would be to check if the week day is `Saturday`. You do this with an IF-statement.

`if week_day == 'Saturday':
   do something`

---

Combining all three steps could result in something looking like this:

```
for item in data['list']:  # step 1

    date = datetime.strptime(item['date'],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # step 2a
    weekday = date.strftime('%A')  # step 2b

    if weekday == 'Saturday':  # step 3
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have your `strptime` usage a bit wrong, right now you're telling it to extract date data from the string `"date"` but what you want is to extract date data from the variable `item["date"]` :

```
for item in data['list']:
    print(datetime.strptime(item["date"],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').weekday()))
```

you also don't need to use the `.get()` function of dictionaries it's much easier and more acceptable to use the square brackets notation

Answer (score 0):

You should use `item['date']` instead of a literal `'date'` to reference the item's `'date'` value. The following will return the sub-dict of the `wind` key of the first Saturday entry:

```
next((item['wind'] for item in data['list'] if datetime.strptime(item['date'],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').weekday() == 5), {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **antimatter**, and especially **user347**. I build upon your suggestions and came up with the following. Note that I expanded on it since I want to have data for Sat and Sun and for 12 and 15 o'clock. Is there a good solution for shortening the 4 if-statements?

```
    for item in data['list']:  

date = datetime.strptime(item['date'],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  
weekday = date.strftime('%A') 
time = date.strftime('%H')

if weekday == 'Saturday' and time == '12':
    if item['wind']['speed'] >= 6 and item['wind']['deg'] >= 180:
        print('Perfect conditions on Saturday at 12 -  wind with ' + 
              str(round(item['wind']['speed']* 1.943846, 1)) + 
              ' knots' + ' and direction: '+ str(item['wind']['deg']))

if weekday == 'Saturday' and time == '15':
    if item['wind']['speed'] >= 6 and item['wind']['deg'] >= 180:
        print('Perfect conditions on Saturday at 15  - wind with ' + 
              str(round(item['wind']['speed']* 1.943846, 1)) + 
              ' knots' + ' and direction: '+ str(item['wind']['deg']))

if weekday == 'Sunday' and time == '12':
    if item['wind']['speed'] >= 6 and item['wind']['deg'] >= 180:
        print('Perfect conditions on Sunday at 12 - wind with ' + 
              str(round(item['wind']['speed']* 1.943846, 1)) + 
              ' knots' + ' and direction: '+ str(item['wind']['deg']))

if weekday == 'Sunday' and time == '15':
    if item['wind']['speed'] >= 6 and item['wind']['deg'] >= 180:
        print('Perfect conditions on Sunday at 12 - wind with ' + 
              str(round(item['wind']['speed']* 1.943846, 1)) + 
              ' knots' + ' and direction: '+ str(item['wind']['deg']))
```

which returns:

```
    Perfect conditions on Saturday at 12 - wind with 13.4 knots and direction: 
    306.511
    Perfect conditions on Saturday at 12 - wind with 14.0 knots and direction: 
    306.001
```

Comment: You can begin by checking if `wind_speed` and `wind_degree` is not a perfect condition (and if so `continue` with next value in loop), and then check if `weekday` is `in` `['Saturday', 'Sunday']` and if so check if `time` is `in` `['12', '15']`. Would cut the IF-statements from 20 lines to 5 lines.